# Best practice for binding drop down lists in 3-tier architecture

Tags: c#, asp.net, 3-tier

I'm a beginner in using the 3-tier approach in development, i got many drop down lists in my application each consisting of 4 or 5 choices. If i stored this data in my database, then according to my understanding of 3-tier approach, i need to create a Data access class and a business class for each of the lists. This means i need to create almost 40 classes for 20 drop down lists, this surely does not sound practical.

Is there a better way to design drop down lists or to store the DDL data in my application ?

Comment: you do not need to create classes for each and every dropdown.You have to just create one DAL and BAL thats it.create functions in these class files and use according your need!

Answer (score 0):

You can have a generic binding class as following.

```
/// <summary>
    /// Common DropDown model
    /// </summary>
    public class SelectListModel
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the value.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>
        /// The value.
        /// </value>
        public int Value { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the item.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>
        /// The item.
        /// </value>
        public string Item { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets a value indicating whether this instance is selected.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>
        /// <c>true</c> if this instance is selected; otherwise, <c>false</c>.
        /// </value>
        public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
    }
```

You can bind any dropdown data into this model and return it to the view.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void DropwonlistBind(DropDownList DDLName)
{

DDLName.Datasource="YourSouce";
DDLName.DataTextField="TextField";
DDLName.DataValueField="IDField";
DDLName.Databind();

}
```